# circa abbreviation after a period - to capitalize or not

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations

I keep getting called out for not capitalizing "ca." in image captions. When I look up in Chicago Style, I see it NOT capitalized. However, when I write a caption I often make it a sort of sentence and then I am criticized for not capitalizing the letter C. Am I wrong either with the capitalization or with the way that I am writing captions?

Example: Seattle Space Needle at sunset, looking west. ca. 1970. Negative # C Linsey AR-3659872 (Courtesy of University of Washington Libraries, Special Collections)

Comment: I have never seen circa capitalized.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in your sentence construction.  *'Seattle Space Needle at sunset, looking west. ca. 1970.'* . Here you've placed *ca.* after a full-stop and you begin the next part with a small letter. Try to write *Seattle Space Needle at sunset, looking west, ca. 1970.*